# Get the count of only disabled type="number" input boxes

Tags: javascript, validation, input

How can I expand this to count all input boxes in a form that is `type="number"` but is currently disabled?

```
let countIN = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
```

I can count all the input boxes (which included checkboxes) but I want to only count the specific disabled boxes only.

Comment: Can you add the related html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (which deals with CSS selectors naturally) with the selector `[type="number"]:disabled`.  For example, as you can see in the example, it's the same selector that you would use in a CSS file to change the background colour for those specific elements.

Note: if you wanted to be *more* specific you could prefix `input` to the selector (`input[type="number"]:disabled`), but it's rare - in my experience - to find an element with a number type that *isn't* an input so you can generally just leave that part out.

```js
const selector = '[type="number"]:disabled';

const disabled = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

console.log(`Disabled number inputs: ${disabled.length}`);
```

```css
[type="number"]:disabled { background-color: salmon; }
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1">
<input type="number" value="2" disabled>
<input type="number" value="3">
<input type="number" value="4" disabled>
<input type="number" value="5">
```

Comment: Oh yeah, looks good too. I just fiddled around and found one below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, I found it:

```
 let countIN = document.querySelectorAll("input:disabled").length;
```

Comment: This targets ALL inputs, not just the number inputs.

Comment: True. I was actually thinking that after I did this. Thanks for pointing it out.